# Changing hyperlink styles in a footer or other document part

Tags: hyperref, href, css

Is there a way to change the hyperlink styles from package hyperref in different parts of the document?

I might want a different style in footers,  or in the text of subsubsections, than the rest of the document.

For example, I have this footer   a specific href:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{  
\color{TextLighter}\myheaderfooterfont \href{https://www.icwealth.ca}{\color{TextLighter}icwealth.ca} | Be Smart Money}
```

I would like any href in the footer to have the  color TextLighter.

Comment: you can use \hypersetup in the footer and change the colors.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.